# VTD-XML JAVA XMLModifier remove whitespace issue

Tags: vtd-xml

I am trying to remove some nodes using XMLModifier using the following code. I am ending with white spaces in between. How can I get rid of this?

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import com.ximpleware.AutoPilot;
import com.ximpleware.VTDGen;
import com.ximpleware.VTDNav;
import com.ximpleware.XMLModifier;

public class VTDWhiteSpaceIssue {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Sample.xml"));
    String query = new String(encoded, "UTF-8");

    VTDGen vtdGenDoc = new VTDGen();
    vtdGenDoc.setDoc(query.getBytes());
    vtdGenDoc.parse(false);
    VTDNav vtdNav = vtdGenDoc.getNav();
    AutoPilot autoPilot = new AutoPilot(vtdNav);
    XMLModifier xmlModifier = new XMLModifier(vtdNav);

    autoPilot.selectXPath("//product/catalog_item");
    if (autoPilot.evalXPath() != -1 && vtdNav.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD)) {
        do {
            String nodeName = vtdNav.toRawString(vtdNav.getCurrentIndex());
            if (!"price".equals(nodeName) && !"item_number".equals(nodeName)) {
                System.out.println("Removing node " + nodeName);
                xmlModifier.remove();
            }
        } while (vtdNav.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING));
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("==============================================================");
    // normalizedQueryNav = normalizedQueryModifier.outputAndReparse();
    xmlModifier.output(System.out);
    System.out.println("==============================================================");
}
```

}

Sample.xml

```
<catalog>
<product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
    <catalog_item gender="Men's">
        <title>Cardigan Sweater</title>
        <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
        <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
        </size>
        <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
        </size>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </catalog_item>
</product>
```

I tried using the following code instead of `xmlModifier.remove()`

```
   long elementFragment = vtdNav.getElementFragment();
   xmlModifier.remove(vtdNav.expandWhiteSpaces(elementFragment));
```

It  fails with the following exception:-

```
com.ximpleware.ModifyException: Invalid insertion/deletion condition    detected between offset 189 and offset 373
at com.ximpleware.XMLModifier.check2(XMLModifier.java:888)
at com.ximpleware.XMLModifier.output(XMLModifier.java:1977)
at vtd.VTDWhiteSpaceIssue.main(VTDWhiteSpaceIssue.java:40)
```

Note:- Sample code executed with vtd-xml_2_13.jar

Comment: I will look into it and get back to you on this... one quick comment: you extract the nodeName out into a string, which is not optimal... you can use matchElement(String s) to directly compare the node name, no intermediate string is created, saving a single round trip of object/string creation and collection.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by fragments overlapping... obviously when you call `expandWhiteSpaces` on node named "size." The trailing white spaces of first Size will overlap with the leading white spaces of the second "size" element. The fix is to call

```
public final long expandWhiteSpaces(long l,
                                    short actionType)
```

For action Type, use WS_LEADING. That should do it for you.